# My website is down - who's liable? Host or Registrar?

Tags: website, host, domain-registrar

I've a website which is often (actually most of the times) is down. I am using one company as a registar and another as a host (changing NS). Before I start talking to them on this issue, I want to know to whom I should talk to? Registrar or my host? Who's on the fault? Thanks

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "down". What error message do you get when trying to connect to it?

Answer (score 4):

Probably neither are liable due to the TOS you agreed to. Next time pay for a decent provider. Remember.. you get what you pay for.

Comment: www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com - And then you find out it's just your garbage internet connection.

Answer (score 4):

If your domain name still resolves to the correct IP then your registrar is fine and you should talk to your host.

You can use ping $DOMAINNAME to see if the domain name resolves to the IP.

Comment: That sums it up. It is very likely the hosting provider unless the DNS provider / registrar is under DDOS.

Answer (score 0):

Why hesitate to call them?

Make sure you register your hosting providers nameservers with your registrar, that way you can modify DNS accordingly through your providers control panel.

Is this shared webhosting, VPS, dedicated? Do you have a static, unique IP? If so, can you access your site via the IP, or FTP to the IP? If so, looks like a DNS issue.

Either way, your hosting provider should be able to get this sorted out for you. If not, drop them.

Comment: Well, it's Godaddy and I am hosting my site on Namecheap. Well, I used a different browser today and it says "can't resolve the domain name"